# Email respondents a copy of their completed Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I am the new coordinator of a high school theatre awards program. I have created an evaluation form for the judges to fill out after they have seen their show. They would like to have a copy of their completed form emailed to them after they submit. The only solution I have found requires them to have an account under our domain name. I do not want the respondents to be able to access and edit the original form but I would like them to be able to get a copy of the form they submitted. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use Google Apps Script and to use the old Google Forms as the new one doesn't include yet a way to add the following script.

To add the script,

1. Open the form in the form editor.
2. Go to Tools > Script Editor.
3. Paste the below code.
4. Save the project and give a name to it.
5. Run once time to authorize it.

---

Note: The original code included a line to add the link to edit the response. That line was converted to a comment to meet the requirements stated in the question.

```
// Adaptation from http://securitasdato.blogspot.mx/2014/11/sending-confirmation-emails-from-google.html

function setup() {

  /* First, delete all previous triggers */
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for (var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  /* Then add a trigger to send an email on form submit */
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendConfirmationEmail")
  .forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function sendConfirmationEmail(e) {
  // e is a Form Event object - see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events

  // Edit this to set the subject line for the sent email
  var subject = "Registration Successful";

  // This will show up as the sender's name
  var sendername = "Your Name Goes Here";

  // This is the body of the registration confirmation message
  var message = "Thank you for registering.<br>We will be in touch.<br><br>";
  message += "Your form responses were:<br><br>";

  // response is a FormResponse - see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response
  var response = e.response;

  var textbody, sendTo, bcc;

  // Get the script owner's email address, in order to bcc: them
  bcc = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Now loop around, getting the item responses and writing them into the email message
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    message += itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() +": " + itemResponse.getResponse() + "<br>";
    // If this field is the email address, then use it to fill in the sendTo variable
    // (Optional) Check that your form item is named "Email Address" or edit to match
    if (itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() == "Email Address") {
      sendTo = itemResponse.getResponse();
    }else{
      // If the form don't ask the respondent email address use the following one
      sendTo = 'sendconfirmationemail@googlegroups.com'; //replace this email address by your own default email address.
    }
  }
 // The following line was commented in order to avoid to include the link to edit the response
  // message += "<br>If you wish to edit your response, please click on <a href="\""" +="" response.geteditresponseurl()="" "\"="">this link</a>.";
  message += "<br><br>";
  textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n");

  GmailApp.sendEmail(sendTo, subject, textbody,
                       {bcc: bcc, name: sendername, htmlBody: message});
}
```

**Reference**

- [Sending Confirmation Emails from Google Apps Forms](http://securitasdato.blogspot.mx/2014/11/sending-confirmation-emails-from-google.html)