# Insert a weekday in Google Forms' date selector

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

We have created a Google form that works perfectly, there is only one issue, and that's the DATE selector, it sends the DATE, but we would like to receive the DATE and the WEEKDAY in the form we receive by e-mail.. is that possible in any way? Have seen many ways for Google Sheets, but nothing for Google Forms... I'm completely new to this so excuse if I ask something stupid, also I have looked in the addons section but there is nothing for weekdays or an enhanced date :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms doesn't include a built-in function to send by email the weekday corresponding to a date set by using built-in questions.

If you didn't found a Google Forms add-on that adds the feature that you are looking for you could use Google Apps Script to send a custom email instead of the default response email. More specifically you could use

1. On form submit trigger and the related event object to call a function every time a form response is submitted including a form response object.
2. Forms Service to get the date from the corresponding item response
3. [Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get the weekday from the date.
4. Mail Service to send the email

Related

- [Email respondents a copy of their completed Google Form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86295/88163)
- [Sending emails onSubmit using Google Apps Script Web Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/93473/88163)
- [Can Google Forms send emails automatically?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/97848/88163)
- [Send a google form result to an email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129662/88163)

Answer (score -1):

This is usually done in post-processing with simple array formula which derives weekday from dates collected by the form.

```
={"weekday"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), WEEKDAY(A2:A, 1), ))}
```

[image: 0]

```
={"weekday"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), TEXT(A2:A, "dddd"), ))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long reply :) We actually don't normally go into the replies sheet, we just take a look at the e-mail the form sends automatically. I will have to look for a way to get the great info you explained into the sheet and that it then sends it by e-mail.