# Send a google form result to an email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need help with the google form.
The problem is this: I want to receive an email with its results for every user who completes the form.
For example, if you had a form that required email, name and surname. I would like to receive an email like this:
"
New registered user
mail: newuser@user.com
name: jon
surname: kess
"

I tried addons, but they either didn't work or were limited to a few emails.
Thank you all

Comment: How many users will complete the form?

Comment: Welcome to webapps. If you want some clarifications about an answer please post a comment under it. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if an answer addressed your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can do that with a simple script.

To write the script you should use the `Script Editor` **on the answers spreadsheet** linked to the form (not the script editor in the form).

- Go to `Tools` -> `Script editor...`
- When in the script editor, erase all the presented code and replace it with the following:

**The code**:

```
// Auto-Confirmation Email to "myemail@xyz.com"

   function AutoConfirmation(e){
      var theirFirst = e.values[2];
      var theirLast = e.values[3];
      var theirEmail = e.values[4];
      var myEmail = "myemail@xyz.com";
      var theWhat = e.values[1];
      var subject = "New Form Submitted";
      var message = "New registered user mail: " + theirEmail + " name: " + theirFirst + " surname: " + theirLast + " has filled the form: " + theWhat; 

   MailApp.sendEmail (myEmail, subject, message);
   }
```

- Save
- Authorize
- Now click on the clock icon on the toolbar and on the new page, set up a trigger for `On form submit` and save the trigger.

[image: trigger]

- Test and Enjoy!

#### Notes

The `e.values` 1, 2, and so on, correspond to the columns on the spreadsheet where the answers are submitted. Keep in mind that the numbering for the columns start with 0. (*Zero being the column reserved for the timestamp*.)

*You can read all about limitations on Google accounts and triggers at: [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) and [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

> #### EDIT (following OP request)
>
> *How I can do bold in the var message?*

I am afraid you will complicate things. I would stick to just changing lines using the accepted `\n`. Please have a look at the updated code:

```
function AutoConfirmation(e){
   var theirFirst = e.values[2];
   var theirLast = e.values[3];
   var theirEmail = e.values[4];
   var myEmail = "myemail@xyz.com";
   var theWhat = e.values[1];
   var subject = "New Form Submitted";
   var message = "New registered user: \n\n EMAIL: " + theirEmail + " \n FIRST name: " + theirFirst + " \n LAST name: " + theirLast + " \n\n Filled form: " + theWhat; 

MailApp.sendEmail (myEmail, subject, message);
}
```

*PS: Please try following the site rules as explained [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129662/send-a-google-form-result-to-an-email/129695?noredirect=1#comment117791_129662) and when in need of clarifications just add a comment, not an answer (as you just did).*

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be simply notified when a form has been submitted, you can [subscribe to changes](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/91588?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) on the responses sheet.

If you want something like a complete digest of each submission, you'll need to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) to take the submitted data from a Google Form, use the trigger `onFormSubmit` and email it to you. Example:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var formData   = e.values;
  var field_1  = formData[0];
  var field_2 = formData[1];
  MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "your_email_address",
     subject: "Testing trigger",
     htmlBody: field_1 + ": " + field_2
   });
}
```