# Send a Google Forms response to specific email address based on form response

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to send Google Forms responses to specific clinicians at my practice depending on whether they have been selected on a drop-down menu in the form. At the moment, Google Forms sends an email to all "*collaborators*" when a form has been filled out.
My goal is that clinicians will only receive an email when their own client fills out the form.

Is this something I can do within the google spreadsheet for the Google Form? Or as an add-on?

Comment: How many clinicians do you have? 3, 10, 50, 200 ? How many questions are there?  3, 10, 50, 200 ? Could you also please share a sample form?

Comment: Which feature are you using to send the email to all "collaborators"? Are you using a script or the Google Sheets built-in notification feature? Also please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Should you have issues applying the code or wish to modify the sent message, please let us know and will help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Similar questions have been asked before but I believe you will get confused trying to modify the code.)*

**What you want to achieve is possible by writing some code (a script) in the spreadsheet linked to the form.**

### Step 1

The first thing to do is to create your form. For the script to work you have to remember just one thing. **The first question MUST be the drop-down list with your clinicians**. Following that you can have as many questions as you like.

### Step 2

After you finish your form and link it to your spreadsheet, you must create an extra sheet named `ClinEmails` (*for clinician Email*).

Then or cell `A1` write the word `Clinician` followed by the names of the clinicians **EXACTLY** as they appear in the form.
Next to them on column `B` you must fill-in their corresponding email addresses, as shown on the attached image.

[image: clinician emails]

### Step 3

Next, go to the `Tools` menu on your spreadsheet and click on the `Script editor`. A new tab will open. Delete everything on the page and paste the code from below.

```
// Send a Google Forms response to specific email address based on form response
// As from: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/132665/

function wa132657(e) {
  //setup the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get the range from OnFormSubmit
  var range = e.range;
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation());//DEBUG

  // get the data for the range
  var response = range.getValues();

  // get the clinician name from the form submission
  var clinician = response[0][1];
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Clinician = "+clinician);// DEBUG

  // get the emails list
  var emailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ClinEmails");
  // get ALL the data from this sheet
  var emaildata = emailSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // check how many rows of data
  var emailLastRow = emailSheet.getLastRow();
  // start the loop through the emails data
  for (var i=1; i<emailLastRow; i++){

    // if the clinician is equal to MyClinEmail
    if (clinician == emaildata[i][0]){
      // there is a match
      //Next, get the email address
      var emailClinician = emaildata[i][1];
     Logger.log("DEBUG: clinician = "+emaildata[i][0]+", email address: "+emailClinician);// DEBUG

      // Finally, send the Email.
      var theirName = e.values[2];
      var theirEmail = e.values[3];
      var theEnquiry = e.values[4];
      var subject = "New Form Submitted";
      var message = "New Enquiry by: \n\n EMAIL: " + theirEmail + " \n Name: " + theirName + " \n\n Regarding Enquiry: \n" + theEnquiry; 
      
      
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailClinician, subject, message);

    }
  }
}
```

Click the save button.
On the pop-up window give your script a unique name. You will be asked to authorize the script. Click on Advanced and authorize it.

### Step 4

Finally create a trigger to run on form submit by clicking on the clock icon on the toolbar as explained [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/129695/). If you're asked to authorize it again, please do.

### To summarize:

Create and link form, create new sheet with clinicians names/emails, copy code, create trigger, test, **enjoy**.

Comment: thank you so much for this! I tried using the code here and it seemed to work but stopped working after I added more than two emails https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382059/sending-email-from-google-sheet-after-a-cell-is-updated-from-google-form

Comment: "_I tried using the code here...???_" Here where? [Here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/132665/117311) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382059/sending-email-from-google-sheet-after-a-cell-is-updated-from-google-form)? I am confused. Also. Where did you add the emails? As mentioned before- please do share a sample form as well as its response sheet.

Comment: _"...I tried the code from the link I gave not the code that you wrote on this page"_. Please go ahead and try the provided code on **this** page. Also, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when 
an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)